# How to find how many websites running on Tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am running several websites on my Apache Tomcat server and I want to know how many websites are running on the port that I am using (for e.g., I use 8080 port normally).

Comment: Shouldn't you know since you should have entries in the server.xml for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

If you log in as manager you can see the full list of the applications running:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list
```